# How do I implement a "listen" action on facebook for non-music content?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, podcast

I'm looking to use the "listen" action for a facebook app. Facebook seems to require that we use their built-in "listen" action, which only seems to connect with music-related objects ... but my content is a weekly news podcast.

What's the best way to go about doing this? Tag my podcast episode objects using the "song" open graph tags, even though it's not music? Is this likely to be rejected upon review by Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in "music.listen" action is indeed very restricted, from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-actions/#listen:

> In order to access the built-in Listen action, you must have the
>   appropriate relationships in place with rights owners. We are slowly
>   increasing the number of developers that can leverage the built-in
>   Listen action. If you are interested, please complete this form and
>   e-mail it to musicdevelopers@fb.com.

That means, Facebook is enabling music.listens only for the right-owners of the content. For a podcast-app I think it will be very difficult to proove this rights.

What you could do: use a custom-action "play" or similar. When using a custom aciton, please keep in mind that you're not allowed to publish this action passively / automatically starting February 15th, 2013! You can only publish these actions, when a user chooses to do so explicitly (which means, an app that publishes all played podcasts automatically is probably a not possible).

What you should not do at all: use a custom action "listen" - this will surely NOT get approved.